# Cordova iOS Universal links issue

Tags: ios, cordova, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have cordova app which opens website (www.example.com) within webview. I have added cordova universal links plugin in my app https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-universal-links-plugin , followed the complete steps, added apple-app-site-association file at the root of my website www.example.com and it is showing json.

I have created universal link **www.example.com/activemember**, I added this as link in another website www.example2.com. when I open this www.example2.com in safari and clicks on link, it opens my app and takes me to active member screen within app.

Problem is that I am showing www.example2.com within an iframe of www.example.com which is being shown in webview in cordova app. when I click this link from within Iframe from app itself, it does not opens the specific screen within my app. instead, it opens www.example.com inside the iframe. appreciate if some one can help.

Answer (score 0):

This project is deprecated, but there is a fork with some errors fixed:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-universal-links-plugin-fixed

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @borgees, the linked project is [abandoned](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/160).

If you are willing to switch from Cordova to Capacitor, [Capacitor has support for deep links.](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links)  This uses [Ionic Plugin Deeplinks](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks), which is actively maintained.

Another option for Cordova is the [BranchIO Cordova Ionic Phonegap Branch Deep Linking Attribution](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking-attribution) plugin.